# How hazard is kitchen next to toilet

Tags: food-safety

The kitchen in my office, in next to a toilet. That might seem ok as many in houses in uk are. But my concern is how safe is it to use things from that kitchen, as if someone has use washroom, he has to pass kitchen, the bathroom opens into kitchen. Should i be concern and use other kitchen and utensils too?